# renewing the \mintinline command to disable italics (or any other alternative)

Tags: macros, minted

For the `minted` environment, you can disable italic comments / preprocessor includes etc by using `etoolbox` and then doing `\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{\let\itshape\relax}`.

Using `\let\itshape\relax` directly can work as expected

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
Regular style: \mintinline[]{cpp}{#include <type_traits>}

Hacky style: {\let\itshape\relax\mintinline[]{cpp}{#include <type_traits>}}

Not italic afterward xD
\end{document}
```

which produces the expected non-italic version:

[image: no italics in hacky style]

However, I want to create a way to basically inject `{\let\itshape\relax` before and `}` after the `\mintinline` calls.  It's a complicated command, though, and I think I don't know what I don't know.  This is what I believe was my most successful attempt, [trying to follow this guide](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-patch), I added this in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro{\NewMintinline}{\mintinline}
\let\OldMintinline\mintinline
% not even adding itshape relax, just trying to redefine...
\renewcommand{\mintinline}[2][\newdef]{\OldMintinline[{#1}]{#2}{#3}}
\makeatother
```

I tried many different variants, but at the end of the day I'm totally lost.  I think it's supposed to be `2` arguments, because `\mintinline[optional]{lexer}{code}` gives `lexer` and `code`, but maybe one of those is optional?

Is it possible to in the preamble somehow do some magic to `\let\itshape\relax` for all the `\mintinline`?  I understand that I could transform every `\mintinline` in the code to be `{\let\itshape\relax\mintinline[]}`...but this is less than ideal ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject the instruction in `\mintinline`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\mintinline}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\let\itshape\relax}{}{}

\begin{document}

Hacky style: \mintinline[]{cpp}{#include <type_traits>}

Not italic afterward xD

\end{document}
```

[image]

Use a similar idea for `minted`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\mintinline}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\let\itshape\relax}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\minted}{\VerbatimEnvironment}{\VerbatimEnvironment\let\itshape\relax}{}{}

\begin{document}

Hacky style: \mintinline[]{cpp}{#include <type_traits>}

\begin{minted}{cpp}
#include <type_traits>
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, awesome -- thanks! Is there a reason why you suggest this over `\AtBeginEnvironment` for `minted`? Or is it just because we're already bringing it in for `\mintinline`?

Comment: @svenevs The latter.